# What is the connected component of $(0,0)$ in the following metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $A_n:=\{\frac{1}{n}\}\times[0,1]$ and $X = \{(0,0),(0,1)\}\cup\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$. I'm being told that the connected component $C_{(0,0)}$ of $(0,0)$ is $\{(0,0)\}$, but there is something I'm not understading.

As far as I know, the connected component of a point, is, in particular, a connected space. So if I'm not mistaken, it should be at the same time, an open and a closed set. Clearly, $\{(0,0)\}$ is closed. But I think it's not open, so this would make $C_{(0,0)}$ larger than the point. What I'm thinking is, if $\{(0,0)\}$ is open, then exists an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $B((0,0), \epsilon) \subseteq \{(0,0)\}$. But I can find a point of $X$ for every $\epsilon$ in the following way.

There exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0} \lt \epsilon$. So the point $(\frac{1}{2n_0},\frac{1}{2n_0})$ is in $X \cap B((0,0), \epsilon)$, so  $\{(0,0)\}$ is not open, so it's not a connected component.

Am I saying something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are considering $X$ with the subspace topology, right? Then $\{(0,0)\}$ is open if and only if you can write it as the intersection of $X$ with some open set $U$ in $\mathbb R$. Also, note that every $A_n$ is a connected component (can you show this?) by itself, this should help.

Comment: It's not specified, but I'm assuming is the subspace topology. I can prove that every $A_n$ is connected, and that shows that $\{(0,0)\}$ is a connected component, but at the same time I have the doubt about what I've written. I can't think of an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains $(0,0)$ and not another point of $X$, and if I'm not mistaken, I've proven that every open set that contains $(0,0)$, contains another point of $X$. I guess my mistake might be here, but I can't find out why

Comment: After researching some stuff, I've realized my mistake. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was to think that a connected component it should be an open set in the larger set. For example, if I take $X = \mathbb{Q}$, each point is a connected component, but no point is and open set of $X$. But, the point is an open set of the set that only contains itself.

So, $\{(0,0)\}$ doesn't have to be an open set, and the thing is, that if I add any other point of $X$ is not connected.

Comment: +1 Right, so the idea is that  a connected component only satisfies the property that there is no larger connected set containing it. This does not imply anything about closedness/openness of that set itself, *as a subset of the larger space* . However, as a subset of *itself*, it is both open and closed and contains no subset which has that property. It is a clash of topologies that can be confusing, so thanks for the answer!